# Pattern with $\sec(x)$ partial sums

Tags: trigonometry, summation, secant

I calculated with Wolfram|Alpha the partial sums of $S(x) = \sum^{x}_{n=0} \sec(n)$ and when I plot them I get a repeating pattern:

[image: Sum[Sec[x],{x,0,n}]]

Which I thought would not happen given the fact that $\sec(x)$'s period is an irrational number ($\tau$). Any explanation for this wave's existance in this equation?

Comment: Notice that the jump around $400$ is actually at $366$, and $366 \simeq \pi/2+58\cdot2\pi$. Since the sequence $\cos n$ is dense in $[-1,1]$, there will be values arbitrarily close to $0$, hence arbitrarily high jumps in $S(x)$: the pattern is thus not repeating, but it looks interesting nevertheless.

Comment: For instance, there will be much larger jumps at $x=51109\simeq \pi/2+8134\cdot2\pi$, and $x=52174\simeq3\pi/2+8303\cdot2\pi$. The error of these approximations are respectively close to $4.4\cdot10^{-3}$ (the first example above with 366), $-8.5\cdot10^{-5}$, and $5.5\cdot10^{-6}$. the value of $x$ in thses three examples thus gets closer and closer to $\pi/2$ (or $3\pi/2$), and the secant gets larger and larger in absolute value. You get $S(52174)\simeq 210856.7$.

Comment: Another way to see the jumps: with $p=51109$ and $q=32537=4\cdot8134+1$, you get $p/q\simeq\pi/2$, and $p/q$ has continued fraction expansion: $[1, 1, 1, 3, 31, 1, 143]$, which begins like the continued fraction expansion of $\pi/2$, which you can find [here](http://oeis.org/A053300) on OEIS. The largest value of $\sec n$ for $0<n<2\cdot10^{7}$ is $15684849$, and $15684849/9985285$ has CFE $[1, 1, 1, 3, 31, 1, 145, 1, 4, 2, 8, 1, 2]$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks for the detailed info! I thought the shape looked familiar and then I realised it looked a lot like the 8th Fourier approximation to the square wave ($ \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^8 \frac{1}{2n-1} \sin\!\left( \frac{(2n-1)\pi x}{2} \right) $) in that it has 8 ''minicrests'' for every crest, and the same goes for the troughs. Any idea of a relation?